# Clicking Button Removes Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I have a popup which automatically loads when the page is loaded, it has a timer on the close button whose time on it varies depending on how many times the popup was viewed by the user. It also has a print button and the popup can be called back up if you press the key 'g'.

My focus is on the 'Print' button. If the 'Print' button has been clicked, I want the value of the timer to forever be 0, aka basically disappear forever. I have tried `clearInterval()` but that has not appeared to of worked and I can't find anything else to help me out.

Please note the timer does not appear to work in the snippet or the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/wt1gb9of/1/) although it does work in my browser when I create an HTML file. Please note the timer is controlled by the `counter` variable. My code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 65 || 103) {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
    }
  });
  
  $(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
  });
});

function printDiv() {
  var content = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
  var win = window.open();
  win.document.write(content);
  win.print(); // JavaScript Print Function
  win.close(); //It will close window after Print.
}

// initialization
var counter = 60;
var timesVisited = 0;
var cookieExpirationDays = 7; // don't expire cookies for a week
// test to see if localstorage/sessionStorage is available (localStorage has no expiration date)

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  counter = 60;
  timesVisited = localStorage.getItem("timesVisited");
  // first time
  if ((timesVisited == 0) || (timesVisited < 1)) {
    timesVisited = 1;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 60;
  }
  // second time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 1) && (timesVisited <= 3)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 45;
  }
  // third time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 4) && (timesVisited <= 8)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 30;
  }
  // fourth time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 9) && (timesVisited <= 13)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 15;
  }
  // fifth time
  else if (timesVisited >= 14) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 5;
  }
}
// No localstorage/sessionStorage. Use cookies 
else {
  timesVisited = getCookie("timesVisited");
  console.log(timesVisited);
  // first time
  if ((timesVisited == "") || (timesVisited < 1)) {
    timesVisited = 1;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 60;
  }
  // second time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 1) && (timesVisited <= 3)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 45;
  }
  // third time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 4) && (timesVisited <= 8)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 30;
  }
  // fourth time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 9) && (timesVisited <= 13)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 15;
  }
  // fifth time
  else if (timesVisited >= 14) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 5;
  }
}
var setMsg = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter >= 60 && counter >= 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 60 && counter < 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:0" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 10) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:" + counter);
  } else if (counter > 0) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:0" + counter);
  } else {
    $(".close").click(function() {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
    });
    $("#timer").remove();
    clearInterval(setMsg);
  }
}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.t {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: visible;
}

#t1_1 {
  left: 256px;
  top: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}

#t2_1 {
  left: 334px;
  top: 87px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t3_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 123px;
}

#t4_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 123px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#t5_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 141px;
}

#t6_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 160px;
}

#t7_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 179px;
}

#t8_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 141px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t9_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 160px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ta_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 179px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tb_1 {
  left: 343px;
  top: 242px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tc_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 278px;
}

#td_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 297px;
}

#te_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 315px;
}

#tf_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 334px;
}

#tg_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 278px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#th_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 297px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ti_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 315px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tj_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 334px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tk_1 {
  left: 286px;
  top: 393px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tl_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 429px;
}

#tm_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 448px;
}

#tn_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 466px;
}

#to_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 485px;
}

#tp_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 429px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#tq_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 448px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tr_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 466px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ts_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 485px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tt_1 {
  left: 326px;
  top: 544px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tu_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 580px;
}

#tv_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 599px;
}

#tw_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 618px;
}

#tx_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 618px;
}

#ty_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 636px;
}

#tz_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 636px;
}

#t10_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 655px;
}

#t11_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 580px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t12_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 599px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t13_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 655px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t14_1 {
  left: 264px;
  top: 716px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t15_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 752px;
}

#t16_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 771px;
}

#t17_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 789px;
}

#t18_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 808px;
}

#t19_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 752px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1a_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 771px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1b_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 789px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t1c_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 808px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

.s1_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s2_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s3_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: SymbolMT_1z5;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.s4_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 578%;
  width: 117.5%;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.PopUp {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.PopUp .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.PopUp .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.PopUp .content {
  max-height: 117.5%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pdf1 {
  width: 935px;
  height: 1210px;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 0;
  border: none;
}

button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2D2D2D;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Print {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.close-message {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 9px;
}

.timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
  <div class="PopUp">
    <div class="timer" id="timer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/87XaOWA.png">
      <p class="close-message" id="close-message"></p>
    </div>
    <a class="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="p1" class="p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">
        <!-- Begin page background -->
        <div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
        <div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcY42CW.png" id="pdf1" class="pdf1"></img>
        </div>
        <!-- End page background -->

        <!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
        <div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Player Selection Criteria Evaluator Cue Card</div>
        <div id="t2_1" class="t s2_1">Skating – speed, quickness, technique</div>
        <div id="t3_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t4_1" class="t s4_1">Forward and Backward</div>
        <div id="t5_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t6_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t7_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t8_1" class="t s4_1">Turn both directions</div>
        <div id="t9_1" class="t s4_1">Stop both directions</div>
        <div id="ta_1" class="t s4_1">Are they in a good position for stability and strength</div>
        <div id="tb_1" class="t s2_1">Passing – technique, control, vision</div>
        <div id="tc_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="td_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="te_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tf_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tg_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and Backhand</div>
        <div id="th_1" class="t s4_1">To moving and stationary target</div>
        <div id="ti_1" class="t s4_1">Vision – do they take a look and select best option</div>
        <div id="tj_1" class="t s4_1">Advanced – board passes, chips, saucer passes</div>
        <div id="tk_1" class="t s2_1">Puck Control – technique, open ice, confined space</div>
        <div id="tl_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tm_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tn_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="to_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tp_1" class="t s4_1">Open carry with speed</div>
        <div id="tq_1" class="t s4_1">Execute dekes and fakes on the 1 on 1</div>
        <div id="tr_1" class="t s4_1">Can they handle the puck in traffic and tight space</div>
        <div id="ts_1" class="t s4_1">Ability to maintain control while being stick checked</div>
        <div id="tt_1" class="t s2_1">Shooting – technique, accuracy, velocity</div>
        <div id="tu_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tv_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tw_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tx_1" class="t s4_1">Velocity</div>
        <div id="ty_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tz_1" class="t s4_1">Accuracy</div>
        <div id="t10_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t11_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and backhand</div>
        <div id="t12_1" class="t s4_1">Wrist shot, snap shot, slap shot</div>
        <div id="t13_1" class="t s4_1">Shot Selection – do they select the best shot for the opportunity?</div>
        <div id="t14_1" class="t s2_1">Game Understanding – Principles of Offence and Defence</div>
        <div id="t15_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t16_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t17_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t18_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t19_1" class="t s4_1">Player understands positional play</div>
        <div id="t1a_1" class="t s4_1">Player supports the puck on the defensive and offensive side of puck</div>
        <div id="t1b_1" class="t s4_1">Player communicates with teammates</div>
        <div id="t1c_1" class="t s4_1">Player has the ability to read and react.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Print" class="Print" align="center">
      <button onclick="printDiv()"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HcXNoMC.png" /></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet has a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` Also note that the nested document.ready event handler is redundant

Comment: you should rewrite your code. It has some unneccessary lines like this one *(timesVisited == 0) || (timesVisited < 1))*

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I don't see that syntax error in my snippet. Also if you were to copy the whole code into an HTML file the code would work.

Comment: @Jonasw I would agree, but since I have been focusing on other problems such as the one I'm describing I haven't gotten around to doing that yet.

Comment: @ChippeRockTheMurph but it easifies debugging, wich is what you want...

Comment: @Jonasw Look at the moment my main concern is getting my 'Print' to remove this timer if clicked forever. I tend to remove unnecessary lines of code and debug my code at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you're trying to do, then you want `clearInterval(setMsg)` to run when you click Print. `printDiv()` is the handler for Print button click events, and nowhere in printDiv() is there a call to `clearInterval(setMsg)`. One approach would be to create a function to do everything that needs to be done to get rid of the timer--you can then call it when 1) the timer runs out, or 2) Print is clicked. If you also don't want the timer to appear when the user comes back, then you'll have to set `timesVisited` in localStorage (or set a cookie) in the printDiv() function. Give the following a try. I tried to simplify the logic of how you set the counter and store times visited, and also excluded the cookie alternative for storage just to simplify the issue for debugging:

```js
function printDiv()
{
    endTimer();
    localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', 4);
}

// initialization
var counter = 60;
var timesVisited = 0;
var cookieExpirationDays = 7;    // don't expire cookies for a week
// test to see if localstorage/sessionStorage is available (localStorage has no expiration date)

// Uncomment below to reset localStorage for testing
//localStorage.removeItem('timesVisited');

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    counter = 60;
    timesVisited = localStorage.getItem("timesVisited");
    if (!timesVisited) {
      timesVisited = 0;
    } else {
      timesVisited++;
    }
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = Math.max(0,60-(15*timesVisited));  
} 

  function endTimer() {
      $( ".close" ).click(function() {
        $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
        $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
      });
      $("#timer").remove();
      clearInterval(setMsg);
  }

  var setMsg = setInterval(function() {
    counter--;
    if(counter >= 60 && counter >= 70) {
      $("#close-message").html("1:" + (counter - 60));
    } else if(counter >= 60 && counter < 70) {
      $("#close-message").html("1:0" + (counter - 60));
    } else if(counter >= 10) {
      $("#close-message").html("0:" + counter);
    } else if (counter > 0) {
      $("#close-message").html("0:0" + counter);
    } else {
      endTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing as `clearInterval(setMsg)`. It also did the same thing as `clearInterval(setMsg)`: Nothing.

Comment: Right, but the question is whether or not in your version clearInterval(setMsg) got called at all when you click the print button. My impression is that it did not. With my modifications, it does. But it's possible, maybe even probable, that I don't understand exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: You modifications did not work when I tested them. My intentions are the following: When you click the button, the timer is set to 0, or disappears entirely. The next day when you go to the page again, you won't see the timer, and for the next day, etc,. I want, when you click that 'Print' button, for it to not only print, but to prevent the timer from showing ever again for that user.

Comment: I see. I edited my answer. Give it a try and see if it does what you want. If you don't want the timer to appear again, then you have to call localStorage.setItem('timesVisited', 4) in printDiv. Then when the user comes back, the counter will be set to 0 so that it won't show.

Comment: Also, in your original code, timesVisited was never set when I loaded your page. On the first visit, `localStorage.getItem('timesVisited')` will return `null`. Since this case is never considered in your series of if-else statements, 'timesVisited' will never be set in localStorage. Also, 'timesVisited'==1 is not a case covered by your if-else statement, so it will never get incremented. My guess is that on your machine, you got 'timesVisited' set while you were developing your code and that you're not seeing things how they'd be for a new user. Try using `localStorage.removeItem` to reset.

Comment: On my machine in my HTML file it changes depending on how many times the program was visited. How about you copy and paste my code into an HTML file and then test it out there. I already have code that has a variable `timesVisited` your edit is basically trying to conflict with that variable.

Comment: That's the first thing I did. As I reconstructed your program, your code didn't work: the timer always started at 60 no matter how many times I visited, and clicking print didn't get rid of the timer. With my modifications, it works for me. It's possible I reconstructed your HTML file incorrectly when cutting and pasting the code you provided. Try resetting `timesVisited` pasting `localStorage.removeItem('timesVisited')` in your html file, load the page, comment out `localStorage.removeItem('timesVisisted')`, and then re-load the page to start fresh and make sure it really works as you think.

Comment: Fixed a bug in my code in the edit. Now if I were to enter the contents of `endTimer()` into my `printDiv` function it would work. But not if I copied your `endTimer()` function and then called `endTimer()` in my `printDiv` function. However, while my code does remove the timer when you click the 'Print' button it only stays there for one time. If you were to reload the page the timer would return. Which is what my question about in the first place.